# Using Word to do a mail merge - want to add special characters to merge data

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a list of first and last names as the data I am using in a mail merge using MS Word 2010.

One of the surnames is hyphenated, and another is a two word unhyphenated surname.

In my document, a long combination of first and last name will wrap onto a second line, but a short one will fit the single line. I want the wrap to occur (when it has to) between the first name and the surname, but it currently occurs on the space between the two words or on the hyphen between the two words of these surnames.

I can think of two solutions, but I don't know how to achieve either.

- I could add a non-breaking-hyphen and a non-breaking space to the data. I cannot seem to do this editing the table of data either through Word or through Access.
- I could add some form of formating between the [[FirstName]] and [[LastName]] fields to say break here only when required (does that even exist?)

Any help gratefully received.